# How To fetch the value of a DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, froala

I have integrated froala editor on my HTML page.  I need to fetch the data I have written inside the `div` with its HTML properties.

Below is my code:

**html**

```
<button>
  click
</button>

<div id="froala-editor-br">
  The editor can use <code>BR</code> tags. When ENTER key is hit, a <code>BR</code> tag is inserted.
</div>
```

**js code**

```
$('div#froala-editor-br').froalaEditor({
  enter: $.FroalaEditor.ENTER_BR
});


    $("button").click(function(){
        var chk = $('#froala-editor-br').html();
alert(chk);
    });
```

And here is the working [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/18svg452/17/)

If you press the `click` button, it is fetching the froala code, not the code I am entering.

Comment: Come on, this `$('div#froala-editor-br').froalaEditor('html.get');` is in the docs!

Comment: do you want something like this? var chk = $('#froala-editor-br').froalaEditor('html.get');

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The froala editor adds its own `div`s dynamically and wraps many elements. If you want only the text inside the resulting editor, you need to change your selector.

So, your selector should be `$('#froala-editor-br .fr-view')` instead.

As in:

```
$("button").click(function() {
  var chk = $('#froala-editor-br .fr-view').text();
  alert(chk);
});
```

As mentioned in the comments, @Smit Raval's answer uses the API for the froala editor and it seems like a better option to use that instead.

Comment: I was going to post the exact same solution right now LOL.

Comment: this works but you should use the api as @Smit Raval suggests

Comment: @scraaappy I agree, his answer is better - I upvoted it accordingly.  This one is just another option.

Answer (score 3):

Just need to update selector in the one line inside button click function to:

```
var chk = $('#froala-editor-br .fr-element').html();
```

---

## ES6 Update

Here's the ES6 version of the same code using template literals and `querySelector`:

```
const chk = document.querySelector('#froala-editor-br .fr-element').innerHTML;
```

Answer (score 3):

Just replace your code with below script.

```
 $("button").click(function(){
        var chk = $('#froala-editor-br').froalaEditor('html.get');
        alert(chk);
    });
```

Here is the documentation link.

[`getHTML`](https://www.froala.com/wysiwyg-editor/examples/getHTML)

Answer (score 1):

Pure JS code

```
let button = document.querySelector("button");
let div = document.getElementById("froala-editor-br");
button.addEventListener("click", function(e){
    alert(div.innerHTML);
});
```